# Meteor/React, redirect route after changeState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, state

I have a problem redirecting my routes with react router after a state change.

In fact, my route is working when I'm using a click event who change the state (currentListId), but it's not working when I delete an element by Id (listId), so after a setState( listSelected: "") ...
My routes still display the /idlistselected instead redirect to /.

Here is some code:

**Page code:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { listSelected: "" };
    this.selectList = this.selectList.bind(this);
}

selectList(listId) {
    this.setState({ listSelected: listId });

    // Here, only the if listId Works
    if (listId)
        browserHistory.push('/admin/todos/' + listId);
    else
        browserHistory.push('/admin/todos/');
}

render() {
    return (
            <ListPanel
                listSelected = {this.state.listSelected} 
                selectList = {this.selectList} 
                lists = {this.props.lists} 
                tasks = {this.props.tasks}
            />
```

**Then The ListPanel:**

```
renderLists() {
    return this.props.lists.map((list) => (
        <List 
            selectedItemId ={this.props.listSelected}
            selectList = {() => this.props.selectList(list._id)}
            key = {list._id}
            list = {list}
            countPendingTasks = {this.countPendingTasks(list._id)}
        />
    ));
}
```

**And finally the list:**

```
deleteThisList() {
    Meteor.call('lists.remove', this.props.list._id, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            this.props.selectList(null);
        }   
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <ListGroupItem 
            className={(this.props.list._id == this.props.selectedItemId) ? 'active' : ''} 
            onClick={this.props.selectList}
        >
            {this.props.list.name}

            <Glyphicon className="pushRight red"onClick={() => this.deleteThisList()}/>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
}
```

If I display the listId in the selectList, I have the past ID when I remove a list .. I can't find why cause I set it to null in the delete function ...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the argument to `selectList` when you are passing it to the `List` component, thus if you call `this.props.selectList` in the child component, the original function gets called with the `list._id`, no matter what arguments you give it.

You can fix this simply by passing the `selectedList` function down without binding an argument, and then just calling it with the `list._id` in the `List` component:

```js
<List 
  selectList = {this.props.selectList}
  ...
```

And in the `List` component

```js
<ListGroupItem 
  onClick={() => this.props.selectList(list._id)}
  ...
```

Now the `null` passed in `deleteThisList` function should get passed properly.

Comment: Thanks, it works really good!! :D Just add (this.props.selectedItemId === this.props.list._id) ? 
      this.props.selectList("") : this.props.selectList(this.props.selectedItemId) in the delete function to keep the active item if the item removed is not the one selected.